# Export-CSV or ConvertTo-CSV for Unlike Objects

Tags: powershell, csv, export-to-csv

Because I need more reputation before I am allowed to add comments to existing answers, I am forced to create my own Question.  But my issue is the same one in this thread:

[How to include all properties of all array objects in csv in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17959386/how-to-include-all-properties-of-all-array-objects-in-csv-in-powershell#new-answer)

The solutions proposed in that thread will not work for me as far as I can tell.

- Sorting the objects based on the number of properties is not safe. 
  Just because an object has the most properties doesn't mean it has
  ALL the properties, which means my CSV is still missing some data.
- Specifying the properties in a $props variable followed by $objects | Select $props | Export-CSV does not seem possible for me.  Because my objects are being created based on data from log files, I do not know every potential Property to look for in advance. Unexpected entries could appear in the logs, and when they do they are probably the most crucial data to include in my CSV.  I attempted Select * but it does nothing differently than if it wasn't there at all.

Anyone got any other ideas? Hopefully this is enough info based on the other thread.

Comment: Are you creating a script that will append to a csv file, or will each run of the script collect data and export to a new csv file(or overwrite existing file)?

Comment: Do you have some sample data that we could play with? Is there a maximum number of properties that you would get? The solution in the other thread is based on not knowing the properties in your data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm taking a guess that you're writing to a new file. Since we don't have a script sample to fix, I'll provide one. Is this what you're looking for?

```
$obj1 = [pscustomobject]@{
    Name = "Name1"
    Place = "Place1"
}

$obj2 = [pscustomobject]@{
    Name = "Name2"
    Alcohol = "Alcohol1"
}

$arr = $obj1, $obj2

#Get all possible properties from the data
$prop = $arr | % { $_.psobject.Properties | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name } | Sort-Object -Unique

#Export data, including all possible properties
$arr | Select-Object $prop | Export-CSV .\Desktop\test.csv -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```

test.csv

```
"Alcohol";"Name";"Place"
;"Name1";"Place1"
"Alcohol1";"Name2";
```

(I think I've made something similar here on SO before, but I couldn't find the answer.)

Comment: I don't think it gets simpler than this. Nice work... again... I suppose.

Comment: This is perfect!  Thank you both so much.  It did highlight a problem with my object construction...I was not sanitizing the attribute names. It wasn't hurting the objects themselves but this caused the Select-Object to error out when it hit a property name containing a funky character (error was 'The specified wildcard pattern is not valid').  A reminder to always sanitize input!