# Using Export-Csv

Tags: powershell, csv, export-to-csv, powercli

I am having some trouble getting the formatting correct for my script.  I am trying to use powercli with VMware to pull host name and IP info and from a vApp and export it to CSV.

So far I have:

```
$vapp = Get-CIVApp -name name_of_vApp
$vms = $vapp.ExtensionData.Children.vm
$output = foreach ($vm in $vms) {$vm | select-object -Property Name;$vm.Section[2].NetworkConnection | select-object -Property IpAddress,ExternalIpAddress;} 
$output | export-csv -Path c:\temp\test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The problem, seems to be the line where I assign a value to `$output`.  For some reason it doesn't add the IP info, even though that works outside of the function or even inside the function without $vm.name.  It just gives me the machine names separated by blank lines equal to the number of IP addresses that server has.

My ultimate goal is to have a three column table with the name of the server, the internal IP address and the external IP address.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem might be because you are outputting two objects instead of one in each iteration. PowerShell generally works best when you return a single object to the pipeline. You can do so in this instance by using the [pscustomobject] type with a hashtable of properties.

I also think it makes sense to use `ForEach-Object` instead of `ForEach` as then you can pipe the output directly on to `Export-CSV`:

```
$vapp = Get-CIVApp -name name_of_vApp
$vms = $vapp.ExtensionData.Children.vm

$vms | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Name = $_.name
        IpAddress = ($_.Section[2].NetworkConnection.IpAddress)
        ExternalIpAddress = ($_.Section[2].NetworkConnection.ExternalIpAddress)
    }
} | Export-CSV -Path c:\temp\test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Note that I don't know if the way you are collecting the IPAddress and ExternalIPAddress properties is necessarily valid here, and don't currently have somewhere to test this part.

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't know about `PSCustomObject`, but it seems like a great tool for many things.  I was also confusing `ForEach` as a alias for `ForEach-Object`.  Very confusing!

Comment: I was able to test and that did it.  I ran into a bit of an issue with powershell returning `System.Object[]` when VMs had more than one IP address.  I was able to resolved this by using `-join`, like so:  `IpAddress = (($_.Section[2].NetworkConnection.IpAddress) -join ',')`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that after the second `Select` you still working with the (filtered) `$vm` object and *not* 
`$vm.secton[2]`, try to [`$vm | Flatten-Object`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46081131/1701026) first.

Comment: I did not know about Flatten-Object.  That will be useful in the future as I am always fighting to get info exported out of powershell.  Thank you!