# How to 'flatten' complex Powershell object (hashtable) for output as CSV entry?

Tags: powershell, data-structures, hashtable, powershell-2.0, data-conversion

I'm generating an object which contains the results of some diagnostics process.
It has the following structure:

```
ProdVersion    : [string]
LastAttempted  : [ordered hashtable]
LastSuccessful : [ordered hashtable]
Pings      : [array of hashtables]
Ports      : [array of hashtables]
Services       : [array of hashtables]
     $ServiceProps = [ordered]@{
         ServiceName = $sName
         Exists = $sExists
         Disabled = $sDisabled
         Status = $sStatus}
```

One such object represents data for one CI (server).
I want to output this object in a 'linarized' form for CSV report, as a line of the following format:
'name:val;name:val;name:val...' where val (if a collection) items are in turn separated with, let's say, ','.

What would be the most elegant approach? I'm lloking for a generic solution not bound to my particular object structure.

**Update**

right now I'm trying smth like this, it works but doesn't include the last 'Services' part in output, can't figure out why -

```
$output = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder

function expand ($object) {
    foreach ($i in $object.keys) {
        $t = $object.$i.gettype()
        if ($t -in ([System.Object[]], [System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary])) {
            expand $object.$i
        } else {
            [void]$output.Append("$i=$($object.$i);")
        }
    }
}
```

**Update 2**

Found out why - it treats key values in `$ServiceProps` (e.g., `ServiceName`) not as `[string]` but as `[Object[]]`, and tries to iterate through its `.Keys`, which is `$null`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PowerShell convert nested JSON array into separate columns in CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45829754/powershell-convert-nested-json-array-into-separate-columns-in-csv-file)

Answer (score 1):

Object serialization is the word you're looking for. 
You can use `Export-Clixml` cmdlet. It will write the object into xml document. 
The other option is to use `ConvertTo-Json -Compress`. It'll output a single line. 
But if you need this line to be exactly in specified format, then I guess there's no other way than to write your own function.

Comment: I can't use Json cmdlets (I know about  system.web.script.serialization.javascriptSerializer though) becasue of compatibility with PS 2.0.
Of course, I meant custom function for serialization, not the built-in cmdlets. I don't see how Export-CliXML will help me.

Comment: @Max I recon you aren't using PoSH v2 any more?

Comment: @Dennis heh, fortunately, not. Moreover, I'm not using Windows PowerShell at all.

Comment: @max Ok, so you don't need an answer for PowerShell then?

Comment: @Dennis 4+ years later? no, I don't.

Comment: @Max Just wondering if this question still needs a solution, or if it's better of being deleted?

Comment: @Dennis this question doesn't need a solution, but I think it's better to keep it. 
I didn't even know questions have retention period on SO...

Comment: There is no retention period per se :) But people will keep finding this when searching for un-resolved questions to answer (as I did) if there is no marked solution.