# Convert nested json to csv in powershell

Tags: json, powershell

I need to import some JSON data am getting into my database. I'd like to use PowerShell and figured out a little, but I need help getting the final piece together.
How to convert following nested JSON to flat CSV in Powershell?
Following is the JSON data :

`$openings = '{"objects": [
    {
      "id": 136691,
      "title": "UX Desginer",

      "description": "Hiring a UX Designer for our Front End Team",
      "position_type": "full_time",
      "is_remote_allowed": false,
      "is_archived": false,
      "is_private": false,
      "state": "Draft",
      "location": {
        "city": "Bangalore",
        "state": "Karnataka",
        "zipcode": "560078",
        "country": "India"
      },
      "team": "Front-end Team",
      "created_date": 1472804002,
      "modified_date": 1472804018,
      "application_email": "recruiterbox-dmcc0616@applications.recruiterbox.com",
      "hosted_url": "https://recruiterbox.recruiterbox.com/jobs/d933h5yh"
    },
    {
      "id": 136691,
      "title": "UX Desginer",

      "description": "Hiring a UX Designer for our Front End Team",
      "position_type": "full_time",
      "is_remote_allowed": false,
      "is_archived": false,
      "is_private": false,
      "state": "Draft",
      "location": {
        "city": "Bangalore",
        "state": "Karnataka",
        "zipcode": "560078",
        "country": "India"
      },
      "team": "Front-end Team",
      "created_date": 1472804002,
      "modified_date": 1472804018,
      "application_email": "recruiterbox-dmcc0616@applications.recruiterbox.com",
      "hosted_url": "https://recruiterbox.recruiterbox.com/jobs/d933h5yh"
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "total": 1,
    "limit": 20,
    "offset": 0
  }}'`

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Comment: Please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You should include an example what output you want. There is no straight forward way to convert a nested format (json) to flat (csv).

Comment: `$x.meta | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation` and `$x.objects | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation` providing that `$x = $openings | ConvertFrom-Json`. Diving into `$x.objects` you can see a property `state` used as `$x.objects.location.state` and `$x.objects.state`. Their different meaning (_country_ vs. _status_) does not matter unlike their identical name if you would expand the property `$x.objects.location`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert nested JSON array into separate columns in CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45829754/convert-nested-json-array-into-separate-columns-in-csv-file)