# How to export specific fields of powershell output to csv?

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

I have recently started using powershell and struggling to achieve something.
I am calling an API in my powershell script, and the output is a list of reports, where each report has a set of properties like reportID, reportname, workspaceId etc.
I need to export this entire output to csv in a proper table format, and also export only one property (workspaceId) of each report to another csv file.

If someone is aware of how to do this, please help.

Below is a part of my script:

```
$reports = Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url 'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/reports?$top=10' -Method Get
$reports | Out-File -Path "D:\2709\PS4.csv"
```

[image: output]

Comment: use ```export-csv``` to generate a csv: ```$reports | export-csv "D:\2709\PS4.csv"```

Comment: `Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url 'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/reports?$top=10' -Method Get |export-csv "D:\2709\PS4.csv"`?

Comment: See: [Convert nested JSON array into separate columns in CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46081131/1701026)

Answer (score 0):

```
#to export all properties
$reports | export-csv "D:\2709\PS4.csv"

#to export a selection of properties
$reports | select-object -property workspaceId  | export-csv "D:\2709\PS4.csv"
```

ok I see, $reports contains a json. in principle you can convert the json to csv by doing this:

```
ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $reports | export-csv "D:\2709\PS4.csv"
```

But this gives you only a usefull output if the structure is flat. If thats not the case we have to flattern the structure first before we can export it as csv.

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering, I did try export-csv earlier, but I got the output as below.
Length
9697

Comment: Yes, this is giving me system.object[] , not the values inside.                                                                                                     
odata.context odata.count value
http://wabi-us-east2-c-primary-redirect.analysis.windows.net/v1.0/myorg/admin/$metadata#reports 33954 System.Object[]

Comment: yes as expected. iRon provided a link above showing how flattern the structure...