# Safe dynamic member access

Tags: powershell, code-injection

In our environment we [detecting vulnerable code with Injection Hunter](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/blob/main/reference/docs-conceptual/dev-cross-plat/security/preventing-script-injection.md#detecting-vulnerable-code-with-injection-hunter). See also: [Security Auditing for PowerShell Scripts](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-injection-hunter-security-auditing-for-powershell-scripts/)

#### Use case

In this specific case it concerns a [`PvsServerBiosBootstrap`](https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/provisioning/7-15/downloads/PvsSnapInCommands.pdf) object, that looks like:

```
$BootStrap = [ordered]@{Bootserver1_Ip='1.2.3.4';Bootserver1_Netmask='0.0.0.0';Bootserver1_Gateway='0.0.0.0';Bootserver1_Port='1234';Bootserver2_Ip='1.2.3.4';Bootserver2_Netmask='0.0.0.0';Bootserver2_Gateway='0.0.0.0';Bootserver2_Port='1234';Bootserver3_Ip='1.2.3.4';Bootserver3_Netmask='0.0.0.0';Bootserver3_Gateway='0.0.0.0';Bootserver3_Port='1234';Bootserver4_Ip='1.2.3.4';Bootserver4_Netmask='0.0.0.0';Bootserver4_Gateway='0.0.0.0';Bootserver4_Port='1234';VerboseMode='True';InterruptSafeMode='True';PaeMode='True';BootFromHdOnFail='False';RecoveryTime='50';PollingTimeout='5000';GeneralTimeout='30000';ServerId='12345678-1234-1234-1234-1234567890ab';Guid='12345678-1234-1234-1234-1234567890ab';Name='ARDBP32.BIN'}
```

Where it is evident to iterate trough the `Bootserver*` properties like: `$BootStrap."Bootserver$($Counter)_Ip"`. This `PvsServerBiosBootstrap` object might be quiet seldom but commonly, objects are often [flattened](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45829754/1701026). <sub>(even I think that this should be generally avoided,)</sub>

#### False positive?

For some reason the Injection Hunter detects a risk on a simplified syntax like `$Object.$Property = 'Something'` and  `$Object.$Property` for a `$Property` and `$Object` like: `$Property = 5; $Object = [PSCustomObject]@{ Property = 'Something' }`

```
Invoke-ScriptAnalyzer -CustomRulePath $InjectionHunterPath -ScriptDefinition {
    $Object = [PSCustomObject]@{ Property = 'Something' }
    $Property = 'Property'
    $Object.$Property = 'SomethingElse'
}.ToString()

RuleName                            Severity     ScriptName Line  Message
--------                            --------     ---------- ----  -------
InjectionRisk.StaticPropertyInjecti Warning                 4     Possible property access injection via dynamic member
on                                                                access. Untrusted input can cause arbitrary static
                                                                  properties to be accessed: $Object.$Property
```

But I fail to see how one might exploit this if the `$Property` is defined in the same script (or even the same scope). Can this than be considered as a false positive?
Besides, I wonder what the cleanest syntax would be to prevent the warning (apart from just suppressing the warning). I have tried things along with `$Object.[String]$Property` but the best substitute I have been able to find so far is which is rather cumbersome:

```
$Object.PSObject.Properties.where{$_.Name -eq 'Property'}[0].Value = 'SomethingElse'
```

In other words, how do I *safely* modify a dynamic object member?

Comment: Where is `$Property` defined?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, IMO that doesn't matter: `Invoke-ScriptAnalyzer -CustomRulePath $InjectionHunterPath -ScriptDefinition '$Property = 5; $Object.$Property'`

Comment: Of course it matters :) If `$Object` and `$Property` are both user-controlled or tainted then the warning is pretty spot on

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, Agree (I meant, it doesn't matter for the warning), so what you are suggesting is that it is actually a false positief for something as: `$Property = 5; $Object.$Property }` (updated the question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule apparently *categorically* flags uses of `.`, the [member-access operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#member-access-operator-) that either use:

- an *expression* (e.g. `.$Property`, `.('Prop' + $index)`, `.$(++$i; 'Prop' + $i)`)
- or an *expandable* string (e.g, `."$Property"`, but *not* verbatim strings such as `.'$Property'`)

> Can this than be considered as a false positive?

With a *static, verbatim* value such as `'Property'` assigned to `$Property` in the *same scope*, arguably, yes - but that is a very specific scenario.

---

A *less* cumbersome workaround is to use *index* notation via the [intrinsic `psobject` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members#object-views):

```bash
$Object.psobject.Properties[$Property].Value = 'SomethingElse'
```

That said, the fact that this is *not* flagged - irrespective of what value is assigned to `$Property` - is arguably a problematic oversight on the part of the vulnerability analysis, as malicious code can use this technique precisely to *bypass* the warning.

---

I encourage you to provide feedback to the module maintainers.
Unfortunately, the `InjectionHunter` module's [PowerShell Gallery page](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/InjectionHunter) provides no link to a GitHub repo, so the only obvious way to contact them is via the [Contact Owners](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/InjectionHunter/1.0.0/ContactOwners) link.

Comment: fyi: I have sent a message via the [Contact Owner](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/InjectionHunter/1.0.0/ContactOwners) link and will keep you posted if anything changes.  See also: [`#2` False positives for InjectionRisk.StaticPropertyInjection](https://github.com/matt2005/InjectionHunter/issues/2)

Comment: Thanks, @iRon. I understand that you probably want to use `$Object.psobject.Properties[$Property].Value` as a way to avoid a warning, but the fact that this isn't treated the same as `$Object.$Property` is a loophole in the analysis.