# Getting System.Object[] issue for JSON Array data in output in PowerShell Script

Tags: json, powershell, arraylist

I'm trying to invoke an API using the Invoke-RestMethod and generate a response that I'm saving in output.csv format, but the API response will be in array format in some places, thus the output format is not considering as JSON and is giving by the System.Object[] instead of original response values. Give assistance to me here.

Below example of original response, where platforms field data is coming as System.Object[] in the output.csv.

**the Original response from API looks like below***
[image: original API response sample]

*** **The code I'm using is****************

```
$response = Invoke-RestMethod 'my_api_endpoint.com' -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers
$response | ConvertTo-Json
$response | Export-Csv "<path>\output.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: [`$response | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53583677/unexpected-convertto-json-results-answer-it-has-a-default-depth-of-2). Please, next time properly [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) your post.

Comment: Hi @iRon, I edited my post and added image, hope this helps better.

Comment: @iRon, the code $response | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99 still giving same.
in the output.csv file getting like below.

"12345","123456","my_application1","abc1","abc1.com","yes","dev","myproduct1","xyz","System.Object[]","app",

Comment: How would you expect a hierarchical structured object like `json` to end up in a flat `csv` file? See also:[Convert nested JSON array into separate columns in CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45829754/1701026)

Comment: As an aside, please, [DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557), see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I'm new to power shell, checking the above link. thanks

Comment: Hello @iRon
I read the link and was able to organize an array of json data into a csv using the following code, but I'm still unsure of how to make it into the correct structure that I was seeking. the code is below.

Comment: $response | ConvertTo-Json
$response | Export-Csv "<path>\input.json" -NoTypeInformation
$properties=@('applicationServerId','applicationId','applicationName','serverName','serverFqdn','serverStatus','serverEnvironment','productLine','datacenter','serverType','serverSubStatus',
  @{Name='platform';Expression={$_.platforms[0]}}
    @{Name='instance';Expression={$_.platforms[1]}}
    @{Name='environment';Expression={$_.platforms[2]}}
    @{Name='platformMasterId';Expression={$_.platforms[3]}}
    @{Name='host';Expression={$_.platforms[4]}}
 @{Name='gateway';Expression={$_.platforms[5]}})

Comment: $response | Select-Object -Property $properties | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation -Path '<path>\output.csv'

Comment: Expected output:-
platforms: [
     {
       environment: 
       gateway: 
       host: 
       instance: 
       platform: 
       platformMasterId: 
     }
     {
       environment: 
       gateway: 
       host: 
       instance: 
       platform: 
       platformMasterId: 
     }]

Comment: What I'm getting with current code:-
@{platform=; instance=; environment=; platformMasterId=; host=; gateway=}","@{platform=; instance=; environment=; platformMasterId=; host=; gateway=}"

Comment: Please open a new question with these details and a (text based) json [mcve].

Comment: Sure @iRon, posted new question with information.