# How can I expand a column from group output?

Tags: powershell

I have a list of objects and grouped by a parameter, "off" in this case. Essentially this tells me the total number of users within that office code.  What I can't figure out is how I can expand the output to group by other things within each group.

```
$u = [System.Collections.Generic.List[psobject]]::New()

# users is the response from Get-ADUser
$users | ForEach-Object {

    # enabled and new hold boolean values, I just removed the logic from this example for simplification
    $x = [pscustomobject]@{
        enabled = boolean
        off = [String]$_.o
        new = boolean
    }
    
    $u.Add($x)
}


$u | Group off | Sort Count -Descending
```

Current output is something like this:

```
Count    Name    Group
-----    -----   ----------------
  117    Div_A   {@{enabled=True;off=DIV_A,new=False},@{enabled=True;off=DIV_A,new=True}...}
   23    Div_B   {@{enabled=False;off=DIV_B,new=False},@{enabled=True;off=DIV_B,new=False}...}
```

Essentially what I'd like to do is expand the Group column to instead display a count of 'Enabled' and a count of 'new'. In the end this'll be piped out to a csv.  I've tried using foreach-object with another group cmdlet but I get undesirable output which breaks the whole table formatting.  I'm not very familiar with intrinsicities of powershell yet.

(im aware using 'new' may be a bad key name to use in practice)

Comment: See: [Convert nested JSON array into separate columns in CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46081131/1701026)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Select-Object` to [calculate new properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.4):

```
$u | Group off | Sort Count -Descending |Select Name,Count,@{Name='EnabledCount';Expression={($_.Group |Where-Object Enabled).Count}},@{Name='NewCount';Expression={($_.Group |Where-Object New).Count}}
```

This will produce new objects each with a `Name` and `Count` property with the values copied from the group output, and 2 new properties, each containing a count of objects within the group with the given value set to `$true`.

Comment: Learning about the expression statement helps me out a lot.

Comment: There are some instances where it's not counting all the Enabled fields.  Looking at a small set count might be 3 or sometimes empty but the group data shows it should be 4.

Comment: I don't think Union is the problem here as all the objects have the same fields, there's no mismatched number of keys.